# Can my ISP see that I am using Tails?

Tags: anonymity, internet-service-provider

If ISPs can do this, then how would my anonymity be affected?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR; your ISP could find out, still they can't see what you're doing.**

Your internet service provider (ISP) manages your connection to the Internet, thus receives everything you send through that connection.

**Your ISP will be able to figure out that you are using Tor**, as you therefor will have to connect to a Tor entry node. After the Tor connection is started by TAILS, **your traffic will be anonymous though**.

The TTL (time-to-live) contained in IP frames emitted by a system usually leaves clues to the general type of OS used (Linux / Windows / MacOS), but this should not allow for a specific association with you using TAILS.

If your ISP actively monitors your traffic to find out you are running TAILS, he likely could: Not from the traffic your system forwards, but from the fact that your TTL matches that of a linux and your traffic is very light, except for the one connection to Tor.

As a countermeasure, **you could run a regular windows machine, with TAILS virtualised in a VM**. That way your traffic looks less suspicious, however, it includes other risks.

Comment: I'll give others a chance though to give their thoughts on this question and then I'll mark the correct answer. Thank you for writing a response.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only thing your ISP can figure out and try to block is that you're using Tor network. But - never the less - it's not how it's intended to be by design: like 10-20 years before we all have had an ISP LAN direct connectivity, but now it's mostly gone for the sake of censorship. So - the only reliable way to be truly protected "in a Tor way" is to start building home LAN's by hand again: nobody can interfere into the switch placed in the multi-flat house or a Wi-Fi between houses, if it's a p2p operated network.